# MySQL get null from procedure parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

in this below simple MySql `procedure` parameters my `procedure` only get `NULL` values

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tsmsp_post_users`( IN `user_id` INT(5) )
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'TEST'

BEGIN
     SELECT @user_id;
END
```

Execute Procedure:

```
SET @p0 = '123';

CALL `tsmsp_post_users` (
      @p0
);
```

Result :

```
@user_id
NULL
```

Comment: can you not just SET @p0 = 123;[as INT] and try

Comment: It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and procedure parameters ([13.1.15 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)), are different variables. [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b267/1)